# Set Property on every 5td row in List

Tags: c#

I'm trying to simplifying some code. The takes a dynamic generated list of ipadresses(I have hard coded the ipaddress list, in the program i comes from a webservice):

```
var pinger = new List<Pinger>{
                new Pinger{Ip = "10.130.143.118", NeedPinging = false},
                new Pinger{Ip = "10.130.143.119", NeedPinging = false},
                new Pinger{Ip = "10.130.143.120", NeedPinging = false},
                new Pinger{Ip = "10.130.143.121", NeedPinging = false},
                new Pinger{Ip = "10.130.143.122", NeedPinging = false},
                new Pinger{Ip = "10.130.143.123", NeedPinging = false},
                new Pinger{Ip = "10.130.143.124", NeedPinging = false},
                new Pinger{Ip = "10.130.143.125", NeedPinging = false},
                new Pinger{Ip = "10.130.143.126", NeedPinging = false},
                new Pinger{Ip = "10.130.143.127", NeedPinging = false},
                new Pinger{Ip = "10.130.143.128", NeedPinging = false},
                new Pinger{Ip = "10.130.143.129", NeedPinging = false},
                new Pinger{Ip = "10.130.143.130", NeedPinging = false},
                new Pinger{Ip = "10.130.143.131", NeedPinging = false},
                new Pinger{Ip = "10.130.143.132", NeedPinging = false},
                new Pinger{Ip = "10.130.143.133", NeedPinging = false},

            };
            int count = 0;
            int countStop = 5;
            foreach (var ping in pinger)
            {
                if (count == countStop)
                {
                    ping.NeedPinging = true;
                    count = 0;
                    return;
                }
                count++;
            }
```

After the list i have a foreach loop with a if statement and combining two counters, the code doesn't look very good. Are there any suggesting to simplifying the code.

Comment: You setting NeedPinging only on one item here. Is that the desired behavior?

Comment: the real problem is that you're calling `return` after setting `ping.NeedPinging = true`. That means it's only going to work on the FIRST match. Just remove that and you'll probably have the behavior you want. (Also, I think your first one will be the 6th element because count == 5 will be the 6th element (0,1,2,3,4,5).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use overloaded [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which accepts index of element:

```
foreach(var ping in pinger.Where((p,i) => (i + 1) % 5 == 0))
   ping.NeedPinging = true;
```

Explanation - second parameter of predicate is index of element. Operator `%` computes reminder of division `i + 1` by `5`. Reminder will be equal to zero for elements with indexes 4, 9, 14 etc, i.e. every fifth element.

---

For readability you can move Nth element selection to extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeEvery(this IEnumerable<T> source, int n)
{
    return source.Where((e,i) => (i + 1) % n == 0);
}
```

Usage

```
foreach(var ping in pinger.TakeEvery(5))
   ping.NeedPinging = true;
```

Comment: I like the custom extension method. This is exactly the kind of thing they were intended for.

Answer (score 1):

You should think about readability of your code too. You may be able to find a very concise form which a year from now will look incomprehensible to you:

```
int itemsToSkip = 5;
for (int counter = itemsToSkip - 1; counter < pinger.Count(); counter += itemsToSkip) 
{
    pinger[counter].NeedPinging = true;
}
```

Comment: at least `pinger[counter].NeedPinging = true` then. And element at index 0 will be set to true with your code...

Comment: What seems to be the problem now?